# How do I set a range of cell values to another range of cells in a different worksheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have quite a few rows of inputs in the first worksheet. I am attempting to create a macro that loops through all of the rows by setting the values in a second worksheet equal to that of each row in the first. The second row runs the calculation and returns the outputs to the first worksheet. Nothing seems to happen when I run this. Any ideas?

```vb
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim rowStart As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    rowStart = 7
    
    lRow = Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = rowStart To lRow
        Worksheets("CalcSheet").Range("C" & 5 & ":" & "Y" & 5) = Worksheets("DesignSheet").Range("C" & i & ":" & "Y" & i)
        Worksheets("DesignSheet").Range("Z" & i & ":" & "AA" & i) = Worksheets("CalcSheet").Range("Z5:AA5")
        Worksheets("DesignSheet").Range("AD" & i & ":" & "AE" & i) = Worksheets("CalcSheet").Range("AD5:AE5")

    next i
```

Comment: Why do some of the addresses use `i` and others just have a hardcoded `5`? I think all of them should use `i`, right?

Comment: I'm also not clear on why the first line has CalcSheet = DesginSheet and then the following 2 lines have DesignSheet = CalcSheet. All of the lines should be going the same direction according to your post, "setting the values in a second worksheet equal to that of each row in the first".

Comment: Maybe you have automatic formula calculation turned off?  Or `Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row` is looking at the wrong sheet.

Comment: You don't need to loop for most of this. You can just assign values straight from one sheet to another if the range is the same size e.g. `Worksheets("CalcSheet").Range("C5:Y"&lRow) = Worksheets("DesignSheet").Range("C5:Y"&lRow)`

Comment: `lRow = Worksheets("DesignSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Tim already answered my question, but just so everyone else knows: I was attempting to run a calculation on one worksheet by looping through row inputs on another sheet. The output would then be returned to the input sheet by row. That's why one sheet is iterative and the other is hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is a bit more explicit in terms of what sheets are being referred to.  Other comments in-line.

```vb
Sub Test()

    Const ROW_START As Long = 7 'use Const for fixed values
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long           'use long instead of integer
    Dim wsCalc As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet
    
    'use worksheet variables and an explicit workbook object
    Set wsCalc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CalcSheet")
    Set wsDes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DesignSheet")
    
    For i = ROW_START To wsDes.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        With wsDes.Rows(i)
            wsCalc.Range("C5:Y5").Value = .Range("C1:Y1").Value  'here C1:Y1 is *relative* to row i
            wsCalc.Calculate 'to be sure...
            .Range("Z1:AA1").Value = wsCalc.Range("Z5:AA5").Value
            .Range("AD1:AE1").Value = wsCalc.Range("AD5:AE5").Value
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

A bit more about `Range` as used above...

`Range()` and `Cells()` are relative to the object they're called on, so

```vb
myWorksheet.Range("A1").Address                  '>> A1     
myWorksheet.Range("B2:C3").Range("A1").Address   '>> B2
```

So we're using `wsCalc.Range()` (fixed ranges) but moving the `wsDes` ranges by calling `Range` on `wsDes.Rows(i)`

Comment: Thanks Tim! That was a huge help. Just for clarification, how do we know when the cells referenced are relative? Additionally, how did we ensure that the row on the Calc page remained the same while those on the Design page iterated?

Comment: See comments added above on relative ranges...